# Correcting incrementally increasing array values within while bounds

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a code resembling the progressing skill of kids in various aspects of basketball: Passing, Shooting, and Dribbling.
I've made an array where each row is supposed to represent a kid, and each column a skill.
Every week (loop) I have it printing the cumulative skill of each player (summing each kid's skills).
Problem:
Each week (loop), every skill should go up by increments relative to the prior skill level. If a skill is <10, it goes up by 3 per loop. Up by 2 if the skill is between 10 and 19, and by 1 if it is between 20 and 30, insinuating that it takes more time to improve skill scores as progress is made.
Skills max out at 30.
The while loops I've used are not effecting the array values, and I am not sure why.
I'd be appreciative if someone could you take a look and mention where I went wrong or explain corrections.

```
package CumulativePractice;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int [][] kids =
            {
                    {2, 1, 0},
                    {0, 3, 4},
                    {1, 2, 3}
            };
    int sum = 0;
    int rows, cols, sumRow, sumCols;
    rows = kids.length;
    cols = kids[0].length;


    for(int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        sumRow = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            sumRow = sumRow + kids[i][j];

            if (kids[i][j] < 10){
                kids[i][j] += 3;

            else if (kids[i][j] >= 10 && kids[i][j] < 20);
                kids[i][j] += 2;

            else if (kids[i][j] >= 20 && kids[i][j]> 30);
                kids[i][j] += 1;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("For week " + i + ":");

        System.out.println("Kid " + (i+1) + " total score: " + sumRow);

    }

    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: `i <= rows` as you are using `i` as an index then when it is equal to `rows` it with exceed the number of elements

Comment: Also, look at the braces in your if-else statement. These need to be fixed aswell. You opened the brace after your `if` clause, but then you didn't close it before the else if. Furthermore, you removed the functionality of your `else if` clauses by putting the `;` at the end.

Comment: Hey there is an error in your `if  else-if`  indentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if each row represents a kid, then why are you using it as a week iterator?
What I mean is that you are using following loop, to print weeks progress:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
```

but instead you are assigning the rows to the total kids:

```
    rows = kids.length;
```

I think, the following is what you need(after correction of logic & errors) :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [][] kids =
                {
                        {2, 1, 0},
                        {0, 3, 4},
                        {1, 2, 3}
                };
        int sum = 0;
        int rows, cols, sumRow, sumCols;
        rows = kids.length;
        cols = kids[0].length;
        int total_weeks = 4;  // Let say we have 4 weeks
        int current_week = 1;
        
        while(current_week <= total_weeks)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nFor week " + current_week + ":\n\n");
    
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) // for each kid
            {
                sumRow = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) // for each skill
                {
                    sumRow = sumRow + kids[i][j]; // get total of current skills
        
                    // Now add the skills for current week
                    if (kids[i][j] < 10)
                        kids[i][j] += 3;
        
                    else if (kids[i][j] >= 10 && kids[i][j] < 20)
                        kids[i][j] += 2;
        
                    else if (kids[i][j] >= 20 && kids[i][j]> 30)
                        kids[i][j] += 1;
        
                }
                   System.out.println("Kid " + (i+1) + " total score: " + sumRow);
            }
            current_week++; // Move to next week
    
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)